# SQL Query 1 have count Function and to get data from another SQL Query 2 where memberid is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

My First Query is

```
SELECT
    memberid,
    count(*) count
From
    dbo.Transactions
group by
    dbo.Transactions.MemberID
having
    count(memberid) > 1
```

[image]

My query 2 is

```
SELECT
    transactionlog.id,
    transactionlog.transactionid,
    transactionlog.transactionamount,
    transactionlog.transactiondate,
    transactions.MemberID,
    GymMember.FirstName,
from
    dbo.GymMember
    inner join Transactions on
        GymMember.MemberID = Transactions.MemberId
    inner join TransactionLog on
        Transactions.Id = TransactionLog.TransactionId
```

Results of Query 2 are givne in below image

[image]

Now i want to have data where query 1 member id and query 2 member id are same

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also don't tag conflicting products; SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different. What (R)DBMS are you *really* using?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it from more than 24 hours and after try and trial i found the solution but Senior can recommend a more proper way to do this My Solution is

```sql
SELECT* FROM( SELECT* FROM 
(select transactionlog.id, transactionlog.transactionid, transactionlog.transactionamount, transactionlog.transactiondate, transactions.MemberID, GymMember.FirstName, GymMember.CellNumber from dbo.GymMember
inner join Transactions on GymMember.MemberID = Transactions.MemberId
inner join TransactionLog on Transactions.Id = TransactionLog.TransactionId) as MYTABLE where Exists 
(select dbo.transactions.memberid,count(dbo.transactions.memberid) From dbo.Transactions Where mytable.MemberID = dbo.Transactions.MemberID  group by dbo.Transactions.MemberID having count(dbo.Transactions.MemberID) > 1)) AS mynewtable where convert(datetime,TransactionDate,103)  between  '2022-09-30 00:00:00' and '2022-10-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean find data where the MemberID from the second query exists in the first query? If so please see query below.

```
SELECT
    transactionlog.id,
    transactionlog.transactionid,
    transactionlog.transactionamount,
    transactionlog.transactiondate,
    transactions.MemberID,
    GymMember.FirstName,
from
    dbo.GymMember
    inner join Transactions on
        GymMember.MemberID = Transactions.MemberId
    inner join TransactionLog on
        Transactions.Id = TransactionLog.TransactionId
WHERE 
Transactions.MemberId IN 
(SELECT
    memberid
FROM
    dbo.Transactions
group by
    dbo.Transactions.MemberID
having
    count(memberid) > 1))
```